# Disable undo function in react-admin for List view

Tags: react-admin

It is possible to set the property `undoable={false}` for the `Edit` and `Create` component. This successfully disables the undo feature.

It seems as if this property is not applicable to the `List` view. Is that correct?

**Use Case:**

The user is in the `List` view. She selects an item and chooses to delete it. The delete shall not be undoable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For List, the undoable property must be specified in DeleteButton:

```
<List {...props} >
<Datagrid>
  ...
  <DeleteButton undoable={true} />
</Datagrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

undoable prop is deprecated, use mutationMode="optimistic" instead.
By deafult mutationMode is set to "undoable" you can change it to one of three modes:

- `undoable` (default),
- `optimistic`,
- `pessimistic`.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.19/CreateEdit.html